# Way To Access A Variable In All Methods Of Class Except Defining As Global Variables

Tags: c++

Is there any way to access a variable in all of my methods in a class(except using global varibles that defines above of cpp file)??

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

foo.h

```
class Foo {
    static int bar;
    void foo ();
};

void foo ();
```

foo.cpp

```
int Foo :: bar = 123;

void Foo :: foo () {
    ++bar; // ok
}

void foo () {
    ++ bar;        // Error! Not in scope.
    ++ Foo :: bar; // Error! Private.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean a static data member of the class?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but I didn't read your question as meaning it is the same across Foo objects which is what making it as static here will do (as well as making it interesting across multi-threaded code). You can also make it just a private variable such as here:

Header:

```
class Foo 
{
private:
    int bar;
    void foo ();

public:
    Foo();
};
```

Class:

```
Foo::Foo() : bar(123) {}

void Foo :: foo () 
{
    // Will update its own bar, but not every other Foo object that exists
    ++bar; // ok
}
```

But maybe the static way is what you wanted :-)